# Python pyQt4 QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyqt4, qobject

I am trying to scrape several webpages and I know the URLs in advance. Using a fairly standard code found here this is what I have:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()
```

Doing a for-loop with the various URLs works fine for the first two, then it crashes with the following:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect 
(null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to 
QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect 
(null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to 
QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect 
(null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to 
QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to 
QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to 
QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
```

My (vague) understanding of the issue after researching similar questions is that the QApplication might not be closed properly from one iteration to the next. I tried pausing the script on each iteration for 5-20 secs without any effect. Could not find any other applicable suggestions. Any help on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shut down PyQt's QtApplication correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923845/how-do-i-shut-down-pyqts-qtapplication-correctly)